# Show url on link hover in AIR HTML control

Tags: apache-flex, dom, air

Does anyone know if there is a simple way of catching the hovered link url in an AIR HTML control? Just like in a browser, I would like the url to be displayed in a status bar but I can't find any event that is raised on rollover of a link. Do you I need to inspect and perhaps manipulate the DOM myself for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using mx:HTML or HTMLLoader, you'll probably have to write a little script of your own to wire the DOM objects up to the AIR container.  Here's one way to do it -- there's probably a more elegant solution out there, but for purposes of illustration, it should suffice.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" width="1024" height="768" xmlns:html="flash.html.*" horizontalScrollPolicy="off">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            private function container_complete(event:Event):void
            {
                addHTMLListeners();
            }

            private function addHTMLListeners():void
            {
                var links:Object = container.htmlLoader.window.document.getElementsByTagName("a");

                for (var i:int = 0; i < links.length; i++)
                {
                    if (links[i].href != "")
                    {
                        var href:String = links[i].href;

                        links[i].onmouseover = function():void { setStatus(this); };
                        links[i].onmouseout = function():void { clearStatus() };
                    }
                }
            }

            private function setStatus(o:Object):void
            {
                status = o.href;
            }

            private function clearStatus():void
            {
                status = "";
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:HTML id="container" location="http://stackoverflow.com/users/32129" width="100%" height="100%" complete="container_complete(event)" />

</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

Hope it helps!